# Azure AD Groups and Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, ssas

I have an AD group with 50 users and this AD Group is added to an Azure Analysis services DataModel Role. Out of those 50 users only 1 user is unable to access the data model, when he tries to connect with PBI he gets an error message that "Either you don't have access to the data model or the data model does not exist".
I am not sure why this is happening for only 1 specific user in that grp.

Answer (score 0):

•   I tried to **recreate your scenario in my environment and created an Azure Analysis services Data model wherein I selected a workspace type as ‘Integrated’ and imported that from a data source (Azure SQL database)** as shown below: -

[image: Microsoft Analysis Services import]

[image: Adding data source]

•   *`Once the data is imported from the Azure SQL database in the local cache in the ‘Visual Studio’, your first data model will be created, once done then deploy it to the Azure Analysis services server as shown below through the ‘Visual Studio’ software`*: -

[image: Tables to be imported]

Then, you can **see the same as shown in the below snapshot wherein you can see the sample database being connected to as a data model**: -

[image: SSAS server in Azure]

Thus, I am successfully able to **access the Azure analysis data model from SSMS tool and check the contents of the sample database wherein I have ‘Contributor’ Azure role and ‘User’ Azure AD role**. Thus, similarly, **would suggest you to please check the role assignments for that user which doesn’t have access to the data model in Azure analysis server**.

[image: Analysis services data model]

[image: Deployment to AAS]

Also, please **`check the user name of the Azure AD user in the group whether it matches a UPN in your connected Analysis Services data model or not. Ensure that the Azure AD user which is unable to connect to the data model is registered with the sample database in the ‘login & security’ of the SQL DB ingested in the Analysis services`**.

Please refer to the below links for more information: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles***
***https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/first-azure-as/***